# PyCharm: how to export the pre-defined bundled spelling dictionary

Tags: ide, pycharm, spell-checking, spelling

Title says it. I'm interested in exporting to a text-file the `english.dic`, `python.dic`, `pythonExtras.dic` etc., which are bundled with the IDE by default (see screenshot).
[image: Default Settings -> spelling option in PyCharm IDE]

The related documentation does not mention how to do it:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/spelling.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/spellchecking.html

Note I did find external resources advising **how to do the opposite** (i.e., import your dictionary to the IDE) http://blog.novoj.net/2010/11/07/how-to-add-your-own-dictionary-to-intellij-idea-spellchecker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such option to extract the bundled dictionaries exactly from IDE, but actual versions of [english.dic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/master/spellchecker/src/com/intellij/spellchecker/english.dic), [pythonExtras.dic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/306d705e1829bd3c74afc2489bfb7ed59d686b84/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/spellchecker/pythonExtras.dic) and [python.dic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/306d705e1829bd3c74afc2489bfb7ed59d686b84/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/spellchecker/python.dic) can be found in [intellij-community](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) github repo.